Kafka Sink Connector for SQL Server failing to read data from Topic
I am trying to connect Oracle DB via Kafka Confluent connector on KSQLDB, and publishing it on SQL Server.
The sink connector is failing to read the data.
The details for the source connector can be found here (The answer shared by me):
Kafka source connector encoding issue | Oracle JDBC Connector
I am trying to publish data on sqlserver using this connector:
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR hsr_user_sqlsrvr1
WITH (
  'connector.class' = 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector',
  'tasks.max' = '1',
  'topics' = 'fournewEncode_',
  'connection.url' = 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;user={user};password={pass}',
  'connection.user' = {user},
  'connection.password' = {pass},
  'insert.mode' = 'insert',
  'table.name.format' = {table},
  'pk.mode' = 'record_key',
  'pk.fields' = 'user_id',
  'key.converter' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
  'key.converter.schemas.enable' = 'false',
  'value.converter'='org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
  'value.converter.schemas.enable' = 'false',  
  'delete.enabled'='true'
);

The connector runs with warning.
 HSR_USER_SQLSRVR1     | SINK   | io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector   | WARNING (0/1 tasks RUNNING)

While going through the logs, it shows this error:
[2024-04-19 11:08:48,737] ERROR [HSR_USER_SQLSRVR1|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=HSR_USER_SQLSRVR1-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Sink connector 'HSR_USER_SQLSRVR1' is configured with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema, but found record at (topic='fournewEncode_',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1713524878471) with a String key and null key schema. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:612)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'HSR_USER_SQLSRVR1' is configured with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema, but found record at (topic='fournewEncode_',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1713524878471) with a String key and null key schema.

The data as seen in topic is in this format:
Key format: JSON or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2024/04/19 11:08:19.755 Z, key: "HG185035", value: {"USER_ID":"HG185035","USER_NAME":"HG185035","PSWD":null,"USER_ROLE":"SME","ACCESS_LEVEL":"R"}

What configuration is going wrong here, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Try with enabling the json schemas on your converters (will first require changing your source). Jdbc sink connector works best with schemas enabled; otherwise it doesn't actually know what any column names or types for the table. As the error says, the key schema is not defined, and it's required for the other properties that were set. For this reason, Avro or Protobuf would be better than json

@OneCricketeer I did define the key and value convertors as JSON in the source connector:
'key.converter' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
'value.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
'transforms.extractInt.field' = 'USER_ID',
'key.converter.schemas.enable'='false',
'value.converter.schemas.enable'='false',
You can see the whole configuration in the link I shared

I'm referring to schemas.enable'='false'... At least for the key converter. That's what's causing the error. But setting to true requires data from the source to have a schema as well

Done that for source and recreated the sink by enabling the key schema property, encountered new error now: Error: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct is in unnamed module of loader 'app')java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct is in unnamed module of loader 'app') @OneCr

I don't recognize this error, but I think it's related to json parsing... the other way to fix the original error would be 'delete.enabled'='false' since the jdbc source shouldn't be sending null value events for deletion

thanks for the help, but when thats set to true then again the same error comes up
